# Can't commit with SVN because I foolishly renamed the files in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, ankhsvn

I didn't realize this at the time, but I committed a terrible mistake when I used Visual Studio 2010 to rename a winform. Now, SVN will not commit the files and I can't figure out how to fix this problem. All the other files (over 1,000) in the project commit without a problem. It's just this one winform, Messenger.

These are the files:
[image]

And this is the error:
[image]

I cannot use the SVN 'move fix' because the option doesn't appear (probably because it needs to pair a missing file with an unversioned file).

I asked this question previously, but now we're narrowing the problem down.

Any ideas?

Comment: Heh, it's always a bad idea to commit mistakes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, you have two choices. To be honest, I didn't even read the details of your problem. These two choices solve a great variety of similar situations without you having to think about it or understand wtf svn has gone bonkers, I'm confident they'll solve your problem, and it's how I would solve that problem if I encountered it:

Plan A:

1. Make a fresh checkout
2. Paste the contents of your old bolloxed checkout over the fresh checkout
3. Perform a commit while adding all the new files.
4. At some point in the future, or maybe right now, think of what the no-longer-used filenames are and delete them
5. Resign yourself to having lost proper svn tracking of the rename.

Or plan B, if you didnt also edit the files:

1. Make a fresh checkout
2. Replicate your work using svn which you mistakenly did with VS

And advanced plan C combines the two by executing plan B and then pasting over the final edited sources from the bolloxed checkout.